# Using an array to make a hex to decimal converter in Java?

Tags: java, hex, converters

I need to make a hex to decimal converter in Java, without using any built-in conversion methods. The hex string is entered as an argument, and another method displays the converted decimal value. I'm pretty sure I know one way to do this, but it seems very drawn out and inefficient.

I really want to know if I can do this using an array to store the hex string input. Since an array starts at 0, is there a way to store each hex character as a separate value in an array? If it's possible, could I then have a loop run for the length of the array, where each character is multiplied by 16 then raised to the power of its array index?

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm really new to programming and want to try to solve the problem this way. Thanks in advance.

In the event that that is not possible, I tried to make my other idea work, but I always get 0 for my output :(

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] hexInput) {
        int finalConversion = convertHexToDec(hexInput[0]);
        System.out.println(finalConversion);
    }


    public static int convertHexToDec(String hexInput) {
        String max = "0xFFFFFFFF";
        int hexValue = 0;
        int tracker = 0;
        int total = 0;

        while (tracker < max.length()) {
            tracker += 1;
            char current = hexInput.charAt(hexValue);
            int numCurrent = max.indexOf(current);
            total = 16 * total + numCurrent;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I'm really new to programming and want to try to solve the problem this way`  Where is your tried part code????

Comment: Are you looking for String method getBytes() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
static long hexToDec(String hex){
    long dec = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < hex.length() ; i++)
        dec += hextToDec(hex.charAt(hex.length() - i - 1)) * Math.pow( 16 , i);// dec += 10; is the same as dec = dec + 10;
    return dec;
}

static long hextToDec(char c){
    switch (c){
        case '1':
            return 1;
        case '2':
            return 2;
        case '3':
            return 3;
        case '4':
            return 4;
        case '5':
            return 5;
        case '6':
            return 6;
        case '7':
            return 7;
        case '8':
            return 8;
        case '9':
            return 9;
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            return 10;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
            return 11;
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            return 12;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            return 13;
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
            return 14;
        default:
            return 15;


    }
}
```